# Segue: Display stack to second View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

Im creating a RPN calculator in swift. I need help to the code to view all my calculations when the tape button is pressed to segue to the secondVC. When the tape button is pressed it will display the calculations entered.The functionality in the second view controller. Im knew to programming. I have implemented `prepareforsegue` in my first VC. I do not know how to pass the stack to `numberOfRowsInSection`

Calculator engine

```
class CalculatorEngine :NSObject

{

    var operandStack = Array<Double>()

    func updatestackWithValue(value: Double)
    {
        self.operandStack.append(value)
    }


    func operate(operation: String) ->Double
    {

        switch operation
        {
        case "×":
            if operandStack.count >= 2
        {
        return self.operandStack.removeLast() * self.operandStack.removeLast()
```

---

Second View

```
class SecondVCViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var array = [""]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
```

Comment: Where is your `CalculatorEngine` instance?

Comment: I haven't added it yet

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be to use the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This is a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) intended to be used for objects that can have at most a single instance. I'm assuming this is true of the `CalculatorEngine` class.

Singletons in Swift are simple: just add the following to your `CalculatorEngine` class:

`static let sharedInstance : CalculatorEngine = CalculatorEngine()`

This creates a class level property which can easily be accessed from anywhere in the app - you can obtain the sharedInstance in the following way:

`let engine = CalculatorEngine.sharedInstance`

This will allow you to access the calculator engine without worrying about passing references back and forth in the various segue methods.

As a sidenote, the Singleton pattern is sometimes regarded as anti-pattern, because in complex applications it can make it difficult to mock classes properly for testing, and also can increase the amount of mutable global state in the app. But if used judiciously, it is ok - certainly it fits your requirements quite neatly. It's also baked into Cocoa Touch -`UIApplication.sharedApplication` is a singleton.

Comment: You can omit the type declaration (" : CalculatorEngine") in the `sharedInstance` declaration since it will be inferred by `CalculatorEngine()`